# Pop-up error: "Entry Point Not Found"

Tags: windows-7, dll

I keep getting this annoying pop-up: "Entry Point Not Found - The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll".

I have run the System File Checker tool but everything came up clean: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

My Windows updates are up to date. I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Does anyone have a simple and straightforward solution to this issue as I'm not particularly tech-savvy?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your local api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll version is too low or does not exist;

The problem I am having is: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll does not exist in my computer (64-bit) C:\Windows\System32, but there is C:\Windows\SysWOW64 . This time I was given an error.

Try the following way :

(1) Delete api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll of C:\Windows\SysWOW64 if we have it.

(2) Reinstall api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (actually this is VC redit.exe)

api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is included in the following program. Once the download and installation is complete, it will be available in both directories, and it will run normally.

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145